# How to get the input speech before it was recognized

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text

how to get the input speech before it was recognized.
for example if I say "hel," and it does not find it in dictionary .or it thinks its another word .
I just want to get the "hel"

Comment: So you're saying that if "hel" exists, you just want to go straight to "hel"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply more details.  What speech-to-text system are you using?  How are you currently accessing it?  What format do you want the input speech in?  (Sound wave?  Lattice of possible phonemes?  Most likely sequence of phonemes?  Etc.)